# CGImageForProposedRect and CGImageRelease

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, cgimage

When I load an NSImage with `imageNamed`, the OS owns the memory, but when I call `CGImageForProposedRect`, Apple says "This may be an existing CGImage if one is available. If not, a new CGImage is created."

If a new image is created, then I would think I have to release it.

I am not getting a crash either way so it is hard to tell what is correct.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [[NSImage imageNamed:resource] CGImageForProposedRect:&imageRect context:NULL hints:nil];
if (imageRef)
{
    // do stuff

    // is this needed?
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is.  Besides, it's hard to tell where you are writing code.

Comment: The question is: when using `CGImageForProposedRect`, do I need to release the resulting `CGImageRef`?

Comment: No need to release. "existing CGImage if one is available" -> once it has been decoded you will get existing decoded image. (Every next call to get CGImage will reuse existing CGImage)